# Which repos replace large git-lfs managed files with links?

Tags: git, storage, large-files, git-lfs

The feature overview on the git-lfs site says

> Git Large File Storage (LFS) replaces large files such as audio samples, videos, datasets, and graphics with text pointers inside Git, while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or GitHub Enterprise.

But this sentence confuses me and seems at odds with the ambiguous accompanying figure.

Are large (managed) files replaced with links on local as well as remote repos, or just on remote repo? What happens when someone clones a remote repo with git-lfs managed files?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the details in the [spec](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/spec.md). It works as following:

large files (files that are tracked via lfs) are never part of the repository. Instead only small pointer files are written into it.

If you commit a large file lfs will intercept and replace the file with a pointer. The file itself is saved into `.git/lfs/objects/{OID-PATH}`.

If you push a large file `.git/lfs/objects/{OID-PATH}` will be synchronized to the storage which stores these large files.

If you would checkout a large file lfs checks if it exists in `.git/lfs/objects/{OID-PATH}`. If not it will download the file from the server.

So yes, large managed files are replaced with links in all repos (what git concerns). Only if you check them out they will get replaced. If `.git/lfs/objects/` does not get cleaned you will have all large files on your system (I don't know if the github client does some cleaning or not).

Comment: If I have an existing file `big.file` in my local repo, and I `git lfs track big.file` I should see the file replaced with a link and the file vanishes? When I push to a remote, where is the large file pushed?

Comment: No, the checked out versions will always be the "real files" (otherwise how sould you work with them?). But if you would check your git repository you will see that the file is not in .git/objects/... but in .git/lfs/objects/... Cloning that repository with a client which has no git-lfs should then see the "link file2". The remote server handles where the large files are actually stored (if it supports git lfs, if not the "pointer files" are probably pushed normally).

Comment: So my local directory structure remains (as it should) the same? If I push to a remote that supports git lfs, what gets pushed? If that gets pulled or cloned, what gets pulled or cloned?

Comment: If you mean "what you see" with "local directory structure", yes. As a user there should be no real difference after config besides a performance gain. If you push you push two things: The "normal" git repository (which contains pointer files for big files) and `.git/lfs/objects` will be pushed to the configured large file storage (which is given to you be the server). If you pull you pull you will pull the normal git repository (with the pointer files). Then when checking out (which is implicit in a pull but whatever) it will the large files from the server.

Comment: If I have a local copy of the big file, and a big file gets pushed to the remote, where are the performance or storage gains. The big file gets (has to get) moved around as it is without lfs, no? And if a collaborator wants to do anything with the large file, they need a local copy as well.

Comment: Yes, but they only need the version they want to operate on. Normally (without lfs) git stores every version in the file. Asume you have a .jpg which is quite large (1gb) and you work with it, commiting each time. Then you have 100 versions, and your repository will be 100gb (it gets compressed, but we will ignore this). If a collaborator now clones your repository he needs to download 100gb. With git lfs he will only need to download 1gb - the newest version of your file. If he wants to check out older versions they will only be downloaded on demand.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. It's not (at all) what's described or illustrated on the overview site though.

Comment: What did you thought it does/is illustrated on the website? I guess they should have mentioned the problem with big binary files in git (blowing up the repository size and thus slowing everything down).

Comment: What it says: It replaces large files with links and puts the large files on a remote server (somewhere). The illustration suggests that this is only done on remotes (but is ambiguous since links and transfers are represented with the same kind of arrow). If all that's going on is that lfs-managed files are limited to "most recent unless checked out", that's all it needs to say.

Comment: @syntonym: If multiple branches of a repo contain the same pointer file (that points to a large object), then upon clone/checkout, will that object be downloaded for all of those branches? Or only for the default branch?

Comment: @WaqasShah As soon as you checkout a pointer file the corresponding file will be downloaded. When you then checkout a different branch that contains the same pointer file lfs will detect that the file is already downloaded and will not download again, but get the large file from the local cache.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @syntonym